# How to show description by default in JSON schema in monaco-editor?

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor

I am using monaco as a json editor, I have the JSON schema configured and the autocompletion works fine. I've given each field a description, which will be visible in the autocomplete show more. Is there a way to make it appear by default? I checked the documentation and couldn't find an API for it. Thank you in advance for your answer.
[The effect I need.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n46C7.png)

The version of monaco-editor : `^0.44.0`

The description should be displayed by default